# Try to pass body in an angular request $Http,giving Bad Request error 400

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I need to call a factory in angular which returns me a json object, the problem is that this request worked for me until I decided to move a param from headers to body of the rest request.
Now I must pass the variable as data( which I think is the same of Body in postman where the request works properly).
This is the actual code:

```
var getData = function(...) {
    return $http({
      method: "PUT",
      url: getStatistics,
      headers: {
        'loginId': ...,
        'token': ...,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: {"...":"...","...":"...","...":"...","...":"...",
             "...":"....","....":"...",
             "datefrom":"2017-01-01","dateto":"2017-10-20"}
    }).then(function(result){
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(result.data);
        alert(result.data);
        return result.data;
    });
};
```

before of the rest restiling, it was like this and it worked properly:

```
var getData = function(...) {
    return $http({
      method: "PUT",
      url: getStatistics,
      headers: {
        'loginId': ...,
        'token': ...,
        'data': {"...":"...","...":"...","...":"...","...":"...",
                 "...":"....","....":"...",
                 "datefrom":"2017-01-01","dateto":"2017-10-20"
          }
      },

    }).then(function(result){
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(result.data);
        alert(result.data);
        return result.data;
    });
};
```

Here the screenshots of the Postman:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the server code?  What is the expected behavior?  What is actually happening?  What did your code look like before you moved the header into the body?

Comment: I am working with an other guy who wrote the rest service, he decided to move the dataObject( which is rappresented by "...":"...") from the headers to the body of the request.

Comment: what is the api signature looks  like? if its webapi2  it has to use [frombody]

Comment: I really don't know if he used webapi2... so sorry

Comment: Do you know if the rest endpoint *supports* content in the body?

Comment: I think, because if I send the same request using postman passing the same data in the body, it works

Comment: can you add snap of post man here ?

Comment: added right now

Comment: have you try JSON.stringify() with your data?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't work... I really don't understand why